# Can a grappled opponent still move?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, grapple, hunter-the-vigil

Can a grappled opponent still move? What if multiple people are grappling it?

This situation came up today when our hunter cell managed to grapple a Garou with it only having two dice to try and break free. The issue occurred when it tried to escape through a doorway to the Underworld (or whatever the realm of spirits is called). We still managed to kill it, but it almost got away because it was agreed that it could move at half speed, but I would like to know for certain for future chapters.

Answer (score 1):

## Technically Yes, they can move, til Immobilised

Grappling is on Page 157-158 of WoD core.

Nothing in there says the grappled can't move.
The rules don't really make much mention of moving at all though, in the grapple section.
Normally, for humans, I might say they basically can't move around but in the case of something so big and strong as a Garou, I would allow them to. See section below.

Basically for grappling you must initiate grapple (basically an attack).
Then then next turn you fight for control of the grapple.
The person in control may apply one of many manoeuvres including:

- Break Free (ie end grapple)
- Deal damage (crush),
- Go Prone
- Immobilise

Immobilise is best suited to the task.
It stops them from taking physical actions (eg Moving).
That would definitely stop someone. You have them in a full body lock basically.
It also makes them "double grappled" that is to say, instead of being allowed to attempt to take control of the grapple every-turn they instead each turn can only try and break the immobilisation, then next turn they may try and break grapple.

Grappling in general is a bit more clear and explicit in New World of Darkness Second Edition.

### Why is is not reasonable to stop a Garou by grappling

The Garou is at least Strength  4 (and quiet reasonably strength 7), and it is size 7 (8 with giant).

From Page 47-48 WoD core:
At strength 4 it can deadlift and move 1 yard  400lbs (~180Kg), it can long term carry 100lbs (~45Kg).

At strength 7 it can deadlift and move 1 yard  900lbs (~410Kg), it can long term carry 175lbs (~80Kg).

This is before it even has to roll or start taking penalties to movement.

At size 7 it is the size of a [Grizzly bear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grizzly_bear#Appearance). We are talking 9ft tall, 1.5m wide, 300+Kgs -- Big.

Stopping a Garou with a grapple is harder than wrestling a bear.
It is only marginally more reasonable to say that a person could stop a Garou by grappling them, as it is to say I grapple and stop a Small Car.
Its not entirely impossible, and depending on the flavour of the particular game being run I might allow it. If it is an action packed game where you are ment to take the monsters head on, then sure! If it is meant to be a game of being scared, and having to trick the monsters then no.

"Its just too strong and too big, it pays no more attention to your grapple than it does to the fleas on it's back."

Generally I would be allowing players to attempt to immobilises -- with the stats a Garou has, it will simply win anyway, or if not then not. I wouldn't say that simply grappling them stops them moving more then a few steps (like I would for humans grappling.)

Comment: That is similar to what we thought. And yes, grappling was rather ineffective, except when she was not able to break free (by that point, she had -7 in penalties), but the grapplers on our side were rolling chance dies unless they used Willpower.